Should a label-map in AWS SageMaker always contain a scaling factor and label names?
I am using CVAT to create my annotations and export them in cityscape format.
For training I use the SageMaker Python SDK as recommended.
So my annotation masks are single channel 8-bit PNG files, as required by the MxNet models.
A similar example of how to train a Semantic Segmentation Model with the SageMaker SDK can be found here.
For my annotations I had to remove label 1 and 2 for now, because there is to little data.
So in my annotation masks I only have [0, 3, 4] values.
Is this an issue?
I thought it might be, so I defined a label map:
label_map = {
    "scale": "1",
    "map": {
        "0": 0,
        "3": 1,
        "4": 2
     }
}

I know label_maps are used to map for example an int array with the class names.
With the above label_map I can train a model, which will predict masks that only contain [0, 1, 2] values.
So far so good, am I using the label_map correct here? I don't understand what is the big benefit here.
Using a label_map like this, won't work:
label_map = {
    "scale": 1,
    "map": {
        "0": {
          "name": "background",
          "color": [0, 0, 0]
        },
        "3": {
          "name": "class1",
          "color": [150, 22, 22]
        },
        "4": {
          "name": "class2",
          "color": [22, 22, 150]
        }
    }
}

Also I think keeping the one channel 8-bit PNG format, feels more consistent and efficient.
The only question in Stackoverflow I found is this one, which helped me to get the model ready, but is not really usefull for my further understanding.
Also I am aware of the documentation .
I find myself uncertain about the scaling factor, and I’m not entirely confident that I’m using the label map correctly. Additionally, I wonder if there’s anything crucial I might be overlooking.
It would be great if someone could clarify things for a new SageMaker user and Machine Learning enthusiast.
